# Downloading a page in Android

Tags: java, beginner, android

I tried to create a class which downloads the HTML source from a link and saves it. I'm a newbie to all this Android stuff, even new to Java, but this is what I have so far.

It seems to work at least, although I cannot see the file since it is hidden.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PageDownloader {

    String Filename;
    String urlString;
    Context context;


    public PageDownloader( Context ctx) {
        Filename = "tmpPage.html";
        context = ctx;
    }

    public void download( String _url ){
        urlString = _url;
        testClass t = new testClass();
        t.execute();

    }
    public void _download(){
        /*
         * First Download content
         * Then Save File
         * 
         */
        String result = null;

        //DOWNLOAD
        try {
            URL url = new URL( urlString );
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[ in.available() ];

            while( in.read(data) != -1 ){
                result += new String(data);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //SAVE
        saveFile( result );
    }

    private void saveFile( String r )
    {
        try {
            File f = new File( context.getFilesDir(), "myfile" );
            if( !f.exists() )
                f.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);//context.openFileOutput(Filename, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write( r.getBytes() );
            fos.close();

            Log.w( "PageDownloader", "got it!" );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("PageDownloader", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public class testClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            _download();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I call it from my onCreate method in my MainActivity.java :

```
PageDownloader p = new PageDownloader(this);
String url = "www.google.com/";
p.download( url );
```

How is this class written? Anything wrong or to improve?

I want to use this code to download several (maybe 5 up to 20) pages when I click on something. After I downloaded the source I want to extract information out of it. Maybe there is a way to make it faster.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! If you use a file manager app such as [Total Commander for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander), you can at least access the external storage of the device. However, I suspect that your file is stored to the internal storage. Either way, I know a couple of things to say about your code... I might review it soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Don't leak `Context`

It's not good to leak `Context` out of an Activity/Service. Your class needs just the output of `context.getFilesDir()`, so store just that:

```
private final File parentDir;

public PageDownloader(Context context) {
    parentDir = context.getFilesDir();
}
```

#### Hardcoded strings

It would be better if the filename was a parameter, not a hardcoded string. If you *must* hardcode, then at least make it a constant:

```
private static final String FILENAME = "tmpPage.html";
```

#### Hide internal methods

It's good to make everything `private` by default, and change to less strict access only when there is a good reason to do so. For example the `_download` method will only be called from your inner class, so there's no need to make it `public`, so change it to `private`.

#### Reading from a stream

The way you read from the input stream has many problems:

- It's inefficient to build long strings by appending to a String with `+=`. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.
- Since you initialized `String result = null`, as you append the input to it your end result will start with the literal string "null". You probably meant to initialize with `String result = ""`.
- The [available method of InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) is not very useful in practice, and it can be misleading. I would recommend using a constant instead.
- You are not closing the input stream after reading from it, which can lead to a resource leak.
- You should not use `e.printStackTrace()`, but log instead
- The comments `//DOWNLOAD` and `//SAVE` are completely pointless

#### Variable and method naming violations

You're not following common naming practices: variable and method names should be `camelCase` and not start with `_`. Class names should be `CamelCase` (starting with capital letter). For example:

- `download` instead of `_download`
- `TestClass` instead of `testClass`

Of course, an even bigger issue with your names is that they are not descriptive. For example the variable `r`, the class `TestClass`, and many others. You should review ALL your variables/methods/classes and give them more descriptive names so your code reads like a story.

#### Suggested implementation

```
private static final String TAG = "PageDownloader";
private static final int BUFSIZE = 1024;

private void download(String urlString) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        in = con.getInputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            builder.append(new String(data));
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        return;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
    saveFile(builder.toString());
}
```

Comment: Very good answer, I'd just like to add that at runtime, it could be helpful for the user to see an AlertDialog or Toast when something goes wrong. Few users have `adb logcat` running when using Android Applications :)